# How to get index value of image using jquery?

Tags: jquery, image

Hi all i am working on jquery i need to avoid adding multiple images  i had written the code here but

always i am getting index value of image is -1 and always if condition fires i dong some thing wrong 
could u plz help me to do that thanks in advance

Here is the code for the first div

```
<div><span class="span1">
<img width="30" hieght="30" name="productimage" src="http://panther:805/Computers.jpg"></span>
<span class="span1">Black_xxl_Slim</span>
<span class="span1">1</span>
<a class="pull-right" href="#"><i onclick="Add(this)" class="icon-plus"></i></a>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the second div:

```
<div class="span6" id="separat">
            <ul class="thumbnails pre-scrollable" id="productbundles">
            </ul>
        </div>
```

here my code follows

```
  function Add(obj) {
           var addedImagesArray = [];
           var img = $(obj).closest('div').find('img').first();

         var image_src = $(img).attr('src');
        var newobj = $('<li class="span2" id="bunle' + id++ + '"><a href="javascript: void(0)"><img hieght=30  width=30 src="' + image_src + '" /></a><h5>' + "Name:" + name + '</h5><span id="pric' + id + '"><b>' + "Price:" + price + '</b></span>');
         if   (addedImagesArray.indexOf(image_src)) {
           alert("Image Already Added");//src present in the array so do nothing or show an alert..
         } else {
           $('#productbundles').append(newobj); //append the image
          addedImagesArray.push(image_src); ///add src to array
         }
      }
```

on above iam having two divs i am adding images from one div to another

but  problem is i am getting -1 index value always plz help me to do this thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare *returned value* of [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) with `-1`, also declare  addedImagesArray in global scope out side the function.

Change

```
if(addedImagesArray.indexOf(image_src)) {
```

To

```
if(addedImagesArray.indexOf(image_src) != -1) {
```

*Declare addedImagesArray in global scope*

```
var addedImagesArray = [];
function Add(obj) {

           var img = $(obj).closest('div').find('img').first();
```

Comment: shortcut: `if(~arr.indexOf(x))`

Comment: For cross browser method, use jquery method $.inArray()

Comment: it's working adil but it's not proeventing from adding duplicate images i need to avoid adding same images multiple times

Comment: Declare addedImagesArray in global scope out side the function, I have updated my answer

Comment: thanks adil it's working thanks for me thanks u very much by 2 by jazakallah

Answer (score 1):

change :

```
if(addedImagesArray.indexOf(image_src)) {
  alert("Image Already Added");
```

to

```
if(addedImagesArray.indexOf(image_src) > -1 ) {
  alert("Image Already Added");
```

Comment: thanks for my reply sudhir it's also wrking but i need to restrict adding same images multiple time could u help me plz